# compile MAKE LIRC on OSX 10.10 fails

Tags: lirc

I am trying to compile lirc latest (0.9.3.a) on osx 10.10, configure is successful, however make fails several times:

```
lircd.cpp:748:6: error: no matching function for call to 'getgrouplist'
        r = getgrouplist(user, pw->pw_gid, groups, &group_cnt);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:648:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'gid_t [32]' to 'int *' for 3rd argument
int      getgrouplist(const char *, int, int *, int *);
```

If I comment out the offending code and run again, I get:

```
irexec.cpp:62:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'strdupa'; did you mean 'strdup'?
                strdupa(SH_PATH), strdupa("-c"), strdupa(cmd), NULL
                ^~~~~~~
                strdup
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/string.h:117:7: note: 'strdup' declared here
char    *strdup(const char *);
```

If I change strupa to strup, then the next failure is:

```
In file included from irpipe.cpp:17:
../drivers/irpipe/irpipe.h:3:10: fatal error: 'asm-generic/ioctl.h' file not found
#include <asm-generic/ioctl.h>
```

Now I know that just commenting out code won't solve the problem, however I am not a C programmer, and I wanted to see how far it would get if I commented out the code.

I have also tried compiling previous versions, they also failed.

Any suggestions on how these can be resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if it helps someone...

configure.ac in 0.9.4b still has this problem.  Solutions is simply:

```
diff --git a/configure.ac b/configure.ac
index 81dece0..ed38bf6 100644
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -346,6 +346,7 @@ CFLAGS="-Werror -Wall"
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([
  AC_LANG_SOURCE([
    #include <grp.h>
+    #include <unistd.h>
    int main(int argc, char**argv)
    {
        int groups[[4]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix above is not sufficient to make it build. LIRC is also affected  by apple bugs in poll(), efforts are under way to handle this. Watch the upstream release-0_9_4 branch for the latest fixes.

Comment: "fix above" should be "fix below", sorry

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the latest LIRC version 0.9.4c

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14063221)

Comment: @etienne disagree that this is low quality. It may not be correct, but if it were, it would be a valid answer. That said, leamas should expand the answer with instructions on upgrading and include a link or excerpt from relevant bug report/patch/release notes.